# Trying to run multiple different functions based on user input

Tags: python

```
tnames = []
inames = []
    def teamEnter():
        for x in range (4):
            tnames.append(input("Please enter a team name:"))
        print(tnames)
        tevent1()
        tevent2()
    #This loops 4 times and asks you to enter 4 team names
        
    def individualEnter():
        for x in range (20):
            inames.append(input("Please enter an individuals name:"))
        print(inames)
        ievent1()
    #This loops 20 times and asks you to enter 20 individual names
        
    
    def intro():
        inp = input("Would you like to hold a tournament for teams or individuals: ")
        # Asks the user to enter as a team or individual
        print (' ')
        TeamOrIndividual = str(inp)
        if inp == "Individuals":
            individualEnter()
        elif inp =="Teams":
            teamEnter()
    #This is the initial home page where you choose between teams or individuals
    intro()
    
    def tevent1():
        print("This is the relay race event")

    def tevent2():
        print("This is the football event")

        
    def ievent1():
        print("This is the tug of war event")

    def ievent2():
        print("This is the dodgeball event")
```

I want to be able to run the tevent1 and tevent2 when the user inputs 'Teams' when the code is run and the ievent1 and ievent2 when the user inputs 'Individuals' when the code is run.

How do i do this?

I tried IF statements to see if that worked by it didnt

Comment: Using `if` sounds like the right thing. Can you show the code when you did that and explain what didn't work?

Comment: Also, your code should return an error as `tnames` is not defined

Comment: i it said that the functions were not defined, I dont know where to put the IF statement

Comment: Please post the code; it isn't helpful to make us guess. At most all we can say is that you put the if where you want to make the decision.

Comment: when is _at the start_ exactly? You should edit your post : we can't really help you right now as your problem is unclear

Comment: I want the program to run the events after the names are entered. I want the tevents to run after team names have been entered and the ievents to run after the individual names are entered

Comment: _run the tevent1 and tevent2 when the user inputs 'Teams'_ is already what you are doing on line 7 and 8 no?

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what’s less clear is how this ought to be indented. Don’t make us guess; please [edit] to fix this. (On the desktop version of this site, paste your program, select it, and type ctrl-K to properly format it as code.)

Comment: thats what im trying to do but it doesnt work because it says they arent defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
tnames = []
inames = []

def teamEnter():
    for _ in range(4):
        tnames.append(input("Please enter a team name:"))
    print(tnames)
    tevent1()
    tevent2()
#This loops 4 times and asks you to enter 4 team names
  
def individualEnter():
    for _ in range(20):
        inames.append(input("Please enter an individuals name:"))
    print(inames)
    ievent1()
    ievent2()
#This loops 20 times and asks you to enter 20 individual names

def tevent1():
    print("This is the relay race event")

def tevent2():
    print("This is the football event")

def ievent1():
    print("This is the tug of war event")

def ievent2():
    print("This is the dodgeball event")


inp = input("Would you like to hold a tournament for teams or individuals: ").lower()
# Asks the user to enter as a team or individual
print()
if inp == "individuals":
    individualEnter()
elif inp =="teams":
    teamEnter()
```